# React - Would'nt React.PureComponent or shouldComponentUpdate always result in not re -rendering if dealing with object?

Tags: reactjs

I found a lot of posts regarding PureComponents shallow comparison but wonder the following:

If React.PureComponent or shouldComponentUpdate only does shallow comparison - wouldnt it mean that if I pass an object via props or compare my state to nextState (which is an object) that it would always result in false even if properties of that object have changed (since its still pointing to the same object and no comparison of the properties is being done), thus, my component would not re-render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may get into case when render is not called since object is the same. Even official docs suggest not passing object values into `PureComponent`.

> Only extend PureComponent when you expect to have simple props and state, or use forceUpdate() when you know deep data structures have changed. Or, consider using immutable objects to facilitate fast comparisons of nested data.

But this will work once you avoid mutating this object passed to `props` in parent component.

If you follow the way as redux‘s reducers do(return new object once anything inside is changed) you will be fine.

But again since it requires additionally attention from anybody it's safer just avoid passing objects and explode all data in list of primitive values passed independently

[UPD] let's take a look into few examples for Parent component's code:

Here MyPure will always re-render because it's different object passed each time:

```
render() {
    let childData = {....}; 
    ....
    return (
    .... 
        <MyPure data={childData} />
```

Here `MyPure` will never be re-rendered because `this.childData` is shallowly the same:

```
changeChild = () => {
    this.childData.a++;
}

render() {
    ....
    return (
    ....
        <MyPure data={this.childData} />
```

This will work well since we are updating different object only after updating something inside:

```
changeChild = () => {
    this.setState(oldState => ({
        childData: {
            ...oldState.childData,
            a: oldState.childData.a + 1
        }
    }));
}

render() {
    ....
    return (
    ....
        <MyPure data={this.state.childData} />
```

So there are few restrictions we need to follow: 
1. don't construct data prop in `render()`(explicitly or implicitly through calling separated method)
2. don't mutate object data prop

Comment: Thanks! you mentioned returning new object like redux , but how would that even look like when passing an object via props?parent component would return new object, then pass it to child?! but then the comparison would ALWAYS result in true meaning a re-render would always happen. Thus, using PureComponent or shouldComponentUpdate for objects will either ALWAYS result in false/always re-rendering (if I dont return new object) OR ALWAYS in true meaning a re-render will NEVER happen?! So, I should ONLY use it for primitive values or immutable data or i will garantied (at some point) get bugs

Comment: I've appended my answer with examples

Comment: Thank you!! A question: if I always create a new object on each setState call, wouldnt the benefit of performance increase by using React.PureComponent be 'topped' by too much memory allocation?

Comment: cannot say without looking into concrete code. typically `PureComponent` is introduced on purpose for components that have heavy `render()`. So you should already know way how to ensure this optimization makes sense for your project.

Answer (score 0):

The shallow comparison will be of the first level of properties within an object. For state, it should NOT be the same object, since you should always call setState with a new object. You should not directly mutate the existing state.